# Unions in c++ and bitwise operations

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, unions

I have seen the following structure in a source code.

```
template<unsigned bitno, unsigned nbits = 1, typename T = u8>
struct RegBit
{
    T data;
    enum { mask = (1u << nbits) - 1u };
    template<typename T2>
    RegBit& operator=(T2 val)
    {
        data = (data & ~(mask << bitno)) | ((nbits > 1 ? val & mask : !!val) << bitno);
        return *this;
    }
    operator unsigned() const { return (data >> bitno) & mask; }
};

union {
    u8 raw;
    RegBit<0> r0;
    RegBit<1> r1;
    RegBit<2> r2;
    RegBit<3> r3;
    RegBit<6> r6;
    RegBit<7> r7;
} P;
```

After a first reading, I found out that an `unsigned` cast of an object whose type is `RegBit` will return the bit number `bitno + 1` of `data`.

However, I don't understand how the `=` overloaded operator is handled. I mean that I understand the syntax, but not what the bitwise operation is meant to do.

And last thing, if you run the code and affect a value to `P.raw`, you'll notice that *∀ i ∈ [0;7], `P.ri.data = P.raw`*.

How is that possible ?
Of course then, the code does what it's suppose to do imho, ie: *∀ i ∈ [0;7], `(unsigned)P.ri` is the (i+1)th bit of `P.raw`.*

Comment: There's a special rule that when all options within a union are structure types that share "an initial common subsequence" of members, those members can be accessed irregardless of which option was most recently written.

Comment: Thank you I wasn't aware at all of that rule

Comment: The funniness in `operator=` has two parts: everything before the first `|` preserves the unrelated bits, everything after copies the new value into the corresponding bits.  And there's a special behavior implemented that for multibit areas, the right number of matching least-significant bits of the new value are copied and high-order bits are ignored, while for single-bit areas, they act like a boolean where it becomes set if the input is non-zero (any bit set).

Comment: BTW there may be some trouble related to the `raw` member, because it doesn't have class type, even though it matches the "initial common subsequence" of the other options, formally that rule doesn't cover it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Would putting `RegBit<0, 8>` as first instead of` `u8` make the rule is followed?

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Yes, that would be a valid way of getting and setting all bits at once.  On the other hand, it wouldn't let you get a `u8&` (or `u8*`) to the data, so it's not quite as "raw" as the current approach.

Comment: At first I thought the title to this question was: `Unicorns in c++ and bitwise operations`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How does the operator= work ?

When you write `P.r2 = 1;` , the assignment operator for the r2 member gets invoked.  So it would have the effect of `P.r2.operator= (1);` which returns a reference to `P.r2`.

Let's analyze the assignment details in the specialized template with `bitno=2`, `nbits=1` and `T` being `u8`:

```
mask = (1u << nbits) - 1u   
     = (1 shifted by 1 bits, aka binary 10) - 1
     = binary 1  (i.e.  it's a binary number with the n lowest bits set)
```

Let's analyse the full expression step by step.  First the left part:

```
mask << bitno ===> binary 100
~(mask << bitno)  ===> binary 1..1011  (aka the bit bitno is set to 0, counting from least significant bit) 
(data & ~(mask << bitno))  ===> the bit bitno is set to 0 in data (thanks to the bitwise &)
```

Now the right part of the expression:

```
(nbits > 1 ? val & mask : !!val) is a conditional operator:  
   if nbits >1 is true, then it's val&mask, aka the n lowest bits of val
   if not, then it's !!val, aka "not not val" which evalauates to 0 if val is 0 and 1 if val is not 0.  
In our case, it's the second alternative so 0 or 1 depending on val.  
((nbits > 1 ? val & mask : !!val) << bitno)  then shifts the 0 or the 1 by 2 bits.
```

Now finally combining all this:

```
data = (data & ~(mask << bitno)) | ((nbits > 1 ? val & mask : !!val) << bitno);

      = (data with the bit bitno set to 0) ored with (val expressed on one bit in the bit bitno, counting from the least significant )
```

Otherwise stated, as a bit value 0 ored with a bit value x gives as results a bit value x, this expression sets the bit bitno to val (val being handled as a bool).

### But what is the union supposed to do ?

The union handles all its members (which are all of the same type `u8`) in the same memory location.

So what would be according to you the expected output of the following:

```
P.raw=0; 
P.r2=1; 
P.r3=0;  
P.r4=1;  
cout << (int)P.raw <<endl;
```

The optimist who wrote your code snippet certainly expects a result of 20  (aka binary 10100).  That may work like this on many compilers.  But in reality this is ABSOLUTELY NOT GUARANTEED according to the standard:

> **9.5/1:** In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of **at most one of the
>   non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time**.

Otherwise stated, if you store something in r2  you're not sure that you will find back the same value in r4. The only thing that is sure is that if you store something in r2 and do not store anything else in the other members, you'll find back in r2 what you've stored there.

### Alternatives to the union

If you need to ensure portability,  you could consider using either [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) or standard [bitfields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

Comment: @LoveMetal thanks for this feedback.  i'm never sure it's clear enough when I explain step by step such bitwise operations, because it quickly becomes very wordy.